# Apacite displays month in references

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am exploring apacite for APA style citations and bibliographies in my documents.

I have gotten `apacite` to read a `.bib` without issue, but when I inspect the references list for accuracy, I noticed that `apacite` inserts the month of the publication into the full citation which isn't APA style for a journal article.  An example follows:

> Fulton, A. S., Gorsuch, R. L., & Maynard, E. A. (1999, March).
>   Religious orientation, antihomosexual sentiment, and fundamentalism
>   among christians. Journal for the Scientific Study of Religion, 38(1),
>   14–35.

The `.bib` entry for this particular example is as follows:

```
@article{fulton_religious_1999,
    title = {Religious orientation, antihomosexual sentiment, and fundamentalism among Christians},
    volume = {38},
    issn = {0021-8294},
    doi = {10.2307/1387580},
    number = {1},
    journal = {Journal for the Scientific Study of Religion},
    author = {Fulton, Aubyn S. and Gorsuch, Richard L. and Maynard, Elizabeth A.},
    month = mar,
    year = {1999},
    keywords = {Homosexuality {(Attitudes} Toward), Religious Beliefs, Religious Fundamentalism, religious orientation \& Fundamentalism \& antihomosexual sentiment, 18–24 yr olds},
    pages = {14--35},
}
```

I would really like the ability to suppress components of entries to fit my needs.  I do know that I could alter the `.bib` file but I fear losing information that could prove valuable later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `apalike` style instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{tbib.bib}
@article{fulton_religious_1999,
    title = {Religious orientation, antihomosexual sentiment, and fundamentalism among Christians},
    volume = {38},
    issn = {0021-8294},
    doi = {10.2307/1387580},
    number = {1},
    journal = {Journal for the Scientific Study of Religion},
    author = {Fulton, Aubyn S. and Gorsuch, Richard L. and Maynard, Elizabeth A.},
    month = mar,
    year = {1999},
    keywords = {Homosexuality {(Attitudes} Toward), Religious Beliefs, Religious Fundamentalism, religious orientation \& Fundamentalism \& antihomosexual sentiment, 18–24 yr olds},
    pages = {14--35},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\cite{fulton_religious_1999}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{tbib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is appealing - I had hoped there would be a way to customize the apacite bibliography, though.  

Do you know if the apalike style is current with the 6th edition?  The documentation I have found indicates a version of apalike from 1992 which makes me curious.

Comment: @Daniel no, sorry. I have no idea if `apalike.bst` complies with the current APA requirements.

Answer (score 3):

I also find this very frustrating. Including the following line somewhere after beginning the document solves the issue in case you never need the month included.

```
\renewcommand{\APACrefYearMonthDay}[3]{\APACrefYear{#1}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a correct citing of month for symposium contributions and conference paper abstract retrieved online. See Chapter 7.04 Meetings and Symposia of APA Manual.

[image]